# T-SQL Query to check if related col is true and update another table col

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this 2 tables SupplierOrder and SupplierOrderDetails which are linked by SupplierOrder PK. Now  I have this col called isComplete in the SupplierOrder table which I want o update to true once all the values in the SupplierORderDetails table's isComplete are all true for that supplierOrder ID. Please see the attachment for the tables. I have tried myself with this query but I think it could be a better way or more efficient.

```
SELECT 1 
    FROM supplierOrder so
    inner JOIN supplierOrderdetails sod 
      ON so.id = sod.supplierOrderID
   WHERE so.id = 1
     AND sod.isComplete= 1
```

[image]

Comment: Please show the query that you tried.

Comment: I added the query in my main question

Comment: why so.id = 1 in your query.most efficient will be that don't update.There is no need of Iscomplete column in supplierOrder.also how do you determine iscomplete value in  supplierOrderdetails tABLE ?this also not require.BTW your query appear ok to me.Hope you don't hv any problem in writing update statement .

Comment: What is `isComplete` column type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, I maynot have correct table names but this should work if u change it

```
UPDATE suplierorder 
SET    iscomplete = 'true' 
WHERE  id IN (SELECT suplierorderid 
              FROM   (SELECT suplierorderid, 
--case statement to set to 0 if complete and 1 if not complete (i.e any other value null or false)
                             Sum(CASE 
                                   WHEN iscomplete = 'true' THEN 0 
                                   ELSE 1 
                                 END) AS complete 
                      FROM   suplierorderdetails 
                      --make sure we only update the new ones and makes sure that your select records are limited to Just not complete records, so if your tables grow this will make your update statement doesn't take a lot of time
                      WHERE  suplierorderid IN (SELECT id 
                                                FROM   suplierorder 
                                                WHERE  iscomplete IS NULL) 
--I am grouping on suplierorderid so that we can add all the iscomplete status of each  suplierorderid column
                      GROUP  BY suplierorderid) A 
--now that the inner query outputs suplierorderid and complete status which will be 0 if everything is complete we are writing below condition
              WHERE  complete = 0)
```

Comment: this looks so complicated for what I am expecting

Comment: @ZAJ I think the solution you have marked as an answer doesnt work for you as the data in your table has null not zero for not completed records see this updated fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fbdc3/1 Eventhough ID=1 has 1 order detail record with iscomplete null it still made the Order record complete I guess that is not what you need

Comment: @ZAJ added comments for you to understand what is happening in the query

Answer (score 1):

All we need is to find `supplierOrderID` where `MIN(isComplete)=1`. So it means that ALL `isComplete=TRUE`

```
UPDATE supplierOrder SET isComplete=1
WHERE id in
(
  SELECT supplierOrderID
  FROM supplierOrderdetails 
  GROUP BY supplierOrderID
  HAVING MIN(CAST(isComplete as Int))=1
)
AND 
(
 (isComplete is NULL ) OR (isComplete = 0) 
)
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/318ee/1)</kbd>

**PS:** Since `isComplete` is a `BIT` type field you can't use `MIN(isComplete)` but you can use `MIN(CAST(isComplete as Int))`

Comment: can you please explain how this MIN checks for all the true in the list. MIN returns the minimum value in the expression..don't get this

Comment: by the way I get this warning when I run the query.Hope it is not an issue/r
Warning: Null value is eliminated by an aggregate or other SET operation.

Comment: @ZAJ If all values for one `supplierOrderID` is 1 then MIN=1 and MAX=1. If at least one of values is 0 then MIN=0. So we juts want to find `supplierOrderID` where MIN=1 it means that all values are 1.

Comment: @vatex 
one issue in this query I see is that it updates all the previously updated cols too. How do we also check that Suplierorder.isComplete is null..something sam pointed out to

Comment: @ZAJ I've changed the query so it now updates only `NULL` or `0` values.

Comment: appreciate your help!!